# Free Download Manager Chrome extension 1.0.18 Change spaces by %20

Tags: google-chrome, download, google-chrome-extensions

I'm using Windows 8.1 , Google Chrome Version 41.0.2272.118  and Free Download Manager 3.9.4.1485.

I needed integrate Free Download Manager and Google Chrome and  I  used [Free Download Manager Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/free-download-manager-chr/ahmpjcflkgiildlgicmcieglgoilbfdp) for  make it the default downloader and it works.

But when download the files change his name, putting  %20 by  spaces and %28 by '(' and  %29 by ')', and It's pretty uncomfortable.

Any suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The downloader is converting the filename to ASCII encoding. I'm not familiar with that extension but maybe there is an option or setting to disable this.

Comment: @Devan I agree with you, but when I use Free Download Manager directly this doesn't happen, then the problem must be of the extension

Comment: Sounds like a big in the extension so report it to the author

Comment: @Ramhound I appreciate your advice, In fact I puted similar question this forum http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/board/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=17059

Comment: I wouldn't be concerned.  Yes, there's something wrong going on, but to me that just looks like an incorrectly-written extension, and not a sign of malicious intent.

Comment: @RussellUhl I suppose that the intention was not bad. I like to use Free Download Manager but the extension is changing filename and I don't like. I wanted to know if anyone knows of another extension or otherwise to integrate that it was not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with a script that I do it in python 2.7 very simple, I plan to keep improving and maybe try to develop at its own extension but for that I need time and learn how do  it. [Here](https://github.com/ciberguille/Replacer.git) is the link to my github code, to the newest in python only need to install [python 2.7](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7/) and put the script where are the files with the names changed and double-click mouse in the script and the names change.

For now I have only added these replacements:

- "%20"     by  " "
- "%28"     by  "("
- "%29"     by  ")"
- "%3"      by  "-"
- "%5B"     by  "["
- "%5D"     by  "]"
- "%5C%27"  by  "'"

If someone is motivated, Make your changes to the code I'm pretty sure that can improve and generalize much more, I promise that I will do in the future